# Best practice MySQL UPDATE/INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-view, join

Disclaimer: I didn't design these tables, and am aware they're not the best way to store this data.  I need advice on the best way to handle the situation.

I have two MySQL tables:

```
`students`
id        int; primary, unique
prof1_id  varchar 
prof2_id  varchar 
prof3_id  varchar 

`professors`
id         int; primary, unique, auto-increment
username   varchar
fname      varchar
fname      varchar
students_id int
comment    text
```

A professor's username may be in any of the last three columns in the `students` table. Professors will need to provide one comment for each student who has them in their row in the `students` table.

The application that is the front end to this database expects two more columns in the `professors` table: student_id and comment. Since each student may have any 3 professors in their row, new rows will need to be added to `professors` whenever they are listed for multiple students.  This means that the `professors` id field will need to auto increment for each new student comment.

What is the best way to accomplish this data transfer with a MySQL query?  I've tried looking at UPDATE in combination with JOIN, but I'm not sure there is even a valid way to do this.  Also, do I need to create another primary key for `professors` since the multiple rows will have the same id?

I suspect that a VIEW might be the best way to accomplish this, but the application on the front end expects the information to be stored in the `professors` table.

One other thing I was considering was that I could create a new table by joining the two tables and have a two-column primary key, students.id, professor.id.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Also, do I need to create another primary key for professors since the
>   multiple rows will have the same id?

Yes. This is good idea.

I wrote simple query that merges data from first table into 2 columns. This is not complete answer, but it can help you a lot:

```
SELECT id, prof1id as profid
UNION
SELECT id, prof2id
UNION
SELECT id, prof3id
UNION;
```

You may use this for view, inserts, but im not familiar with specyfic MySQL syntax and i dont want to misslead you. Please give feedback if it work.

"UNION" removes duplicate rows, you may need to use "UNION ALL" to keep duplicates (like duplicated values in 2 or 3 professors columns).

Comment: Thanks Kamil, I will look into UNION.